# Switch fragment using bottom navigation controller without losing data

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-fragmentactivity

I just begin developing with Android. The first challenge that I am facing now is how to save the fragment data when changing between fragment using a BottomNavigationController (Generated automatically by Android Studio)

I have tried using ViewModel, but since **onDestroy()** is being called every time when switches, the data is also lost. **onSaveInstanceState()** is not being called when switching the fragment neither.

Many methods or solutions I saw online use deprecated functions (Since I am just a beginner, I have no idea what is the new function being used right now)

I hope someone can help me with this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a fragment is changed, it isn't destroyed, instead it is added to the backstack. All the instance variables remain there.
You can retrieve the data in the onActivityCreated method.
Here is an example:

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment

 { 

private List<String> myData;

 @Override public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState)
 { 

super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

 outState.putSerializable("list", (Serializable) myData); 

}

 @Override

 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 { 

super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

 if (savedInstanceState != null) { 

 myData = (List<String>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("list"); } 

else { if (myData != null)

 { //returning from backstack} 

else 

{  myData = computeData(); } } } }
```

Edit :- You can also use shared preferences.
Example :-

```
SharedPreferences shared ;

 shared = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 shared.edit().putString("JSON",jsonString).commit();
```

Read more about storing and Retrieving data using Shared Preferences here : https://www-geeksforgeeks-org.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/shared-preferences-in-android-with-examples/amp/?amp_js_v=a3&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQFKAGwASA%3D#aoh=15850227567178&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Fshared-preferences-in-android-with-examples%2F

Comment: This is the first thing I tried, and it didn't work. I tried then by putting Log.d("onSaveInstance","Saved") inside the "onSaveInstanceState()" since I was not sure when it is being called. The message never appeared in my console until I press my home button.

Comment: This is what I found weird. Because seems everybody says this will work. Even just to be sure, I even created a new project without adding anything, just to see if "onSaveInstanceState()" will be called when I switch fragment. The result is the same, "onDestroy()" is being called every time when I switch fragment

Comment: I will try this now, and give you feedback! Thanks a lot!. I found this weird too since I just start with Android, it is a bit frustrating so far

Comment: It works well! Thanks a lot! Just I still can't figure out why onSaveInstanceState() doesn't work as it should be :(